# Is "The Jesus Incident"'s generating chlorine gas from seawater feasible?

Tags: frank-herbert

In an important scene in Frank Herbert's "The Jesus Incident", one of the characters generates chlorine gas by running a "high voltage" current through seawater.

**Is it possible to generate molecular chlorine by running a current through salt-water in reality?**

Although this is an alien planet, we presume that the seawater is roughly the same as terrestrial seawater.  The "high voltage" is not otherwise described, so we don't know if it's DC, AC, nor the other electrical characteristics (amperage, wattage, etc.).

Comment: @DVK Thank you for editing my question into a more acceptable form

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, it is the [primary method](http://www.lenntech.com/chemistry/electolytic-chlorine-caustic.htm) more or less for generating chlorine gas. You perform electrolysis on brine. It must contain sodium chloride in large amounts in order to generate said gas.